# The link for duplicate answers is rendered as plain text

Tags: bug, flags, hyperlinks

I was looking at an automatic flag for a duplicate answer on Drupal Answers, and I noticed the link is rendered as plain text, not a link.

[image: screenshot]

If that makes any difference, I am a moderator on DA.